# Communities: are site.com licenses required?

Tags: community, licenses, site.com

I've started playing around with Communities in a developer instance (we have a production instance that is old enough that we can still use Customer Portals) and got it all set up fine, was able to brand and customize for the most part. My question has to do with the semi-clear explanations around necessary site.com licenses if you choose to use site.com to customize any pages going that route.

The best I can gather based on numerous [success community posts such as this](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181865&language=en_US)  is that you can use site.com studio/designer under your communities with no extra licenses, but if you want to tap into full fledged site.com build-outs then of course you would need to requisite licenses.

Has anyone made that transition and can confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Salesforce knowledge article confirming this (in very few words!) :

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181865&language=en_US

We are in the process of switching from a customer portal to a community and in the manage communities page we have the following options for custom pages:

[image]

Note that we haven't done anything at all with regard to licenses - communities were automatically enabled for us as we have a set of portal licenses and the site.com option was available immediately.  We didn't end up using it as we needed tighter integration with our data than site.com allows so we went with the Force.com option instead.  We did build out a bunch of Site.com custom pages inside the community using the studio.

The help seems to be pretty clear on this - from the customizing communities with site.com help topic at:

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_communities_overview.htm&language=en_US

> Each community has one associated Site.com site that lets you add
>   custom, branded pages to your community. By default, Site.com pages
>   are publicly available and don’t require login, but you can also
>   create private pages that only community members can access.
>
> ...
>
> Communities users with the “Create and Manage Communities” permission
>   automatically have full site administrator access to a community’s
>   Site.com site.

Comment: That's the same article I referenced :) It appears to explain it straight forward, but I was more interested to hear from those who have actually setup communities in production. Primarily due to other threads over at salesforce success where there is confusion around this

Comment: I've updated the answer based on our experience.